# Popup message showing content from a block

Tags: blocks, javascript

I have a block, and I want to display the content of that block into a popup message. This is my code.

```
function darksite_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/media/darksite'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pop up screen configuration',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('darksite_config_page'),
    'access arguments' => array('adminster pop up dark screen'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

  return $items;
}

function darksite_config_page() {
  $form['darksite_status'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Enable pop up screen'),
    '#description' => t('When enabled, a pop up screen will be displayed on the home page.'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('darksite_status', 0)
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function darksite_block_info() {
  $blocks['popup_dark_screen'] = array(
    'info' => t('Pop up Dark Screen')
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function darksite_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'popup_dark_screen':
      $block['subject'] = t('Pop up Dark Screen');
      $block['content'] = get_darksite_popup();
  }

  return $block;
}

function get_darksite_popup() {
  $popup_message_parameters = array(
    'title' => t('Information'),
    'body' => t('You have completed the work'),
    'check_cookie' => TRUE,
  );
  if (variable_get('darksite_status', 0))
   {
  // if the check box is checked.
   popup_message_show_message($popup_message_parameters);
    } 
}
```

The code does not work. I have installed the model of popup message, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is it not working for you? is it making it popup or getting the message?

Comment: the code does not work I mean dose not work popup

Comment: have you tried it without the print? just popup_message_show_message($popup_message_parameters);

Comment: and when do you want to display the popup?

Comment: on the front page

Comment: do you want to show the same message or does the message depend on something?

Comment: i would to show the same massage as on block contant

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7204/discussion-between-mohammed-shameem-and-tose-sharef)

Comment: could you please open your skype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be printing `popup_message_show_message()`; it just includes all the necessary files and show your message. Just remove the `print` part and try that way.

```
function popup_message_show_message($popup_message_parameters) {
  drupal_add_js(array(
      'popup_message' => $popup_message_parameters
    ), 'setting');
  drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.cookie.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'popup_message') . '/js/popup.js');
  $default_style = drupal_get_path('module', 'popup_message') . '/styles/default/' . POPUP_MESSAGE_CSS_NAME;
  $style = variable_get('popup_message_style', $default_style);
  if (!file_exists($style)) {
    $style = $default_style;
  }
  drupal_add_css($style);
}
```

Also, never use `print_r()` directly. Either use this:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($variable, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

Or install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and call the `dpm()` function this way: `dpm($variable)`. It will use [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) to display all attributes / elements, which is times better for debugging and will not cause any errors as `print_r()`.